# How to toggle between two methods in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my Reactjs Weather project I have two methods - `fetchWeather()` and `getWeather()`. `fetchWeather` method tracks the user current location and displays weather, whereas `getWeather` gets the city input and displays weather. I have created `notifyChange` method which toggles both these methods. See below code for reference

App.js

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
      // Tracking the location and 
      // Setting the state of latitude and longitude values
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (position) => {
        this.setState({
          lat:  position.coords.latitude.toFixed(3),
          lon: position.coords.longitude.toFixed(3)
        }, () => {
            this.fetchWeather()
        })

      },
      (error) => {
        toast.error(`${error.message}`,{
          autoClose: 3000
        });
    },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 50000,
        maximumAge: 1000
      })
  }

fetchWeather = async () => {
// I have added this code now to set lat and lon values
this.setState({lat: this.state.lat,lon:this.state.lon})

const unitType = (this.state.unit === 'C') ? 'M' : 'I';
const {lat, lon} = this.state

// Current Weather fetch(`${CURRENT_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=${unitType}&key=${API_KEY3}`)
  .then(res => res.json()).then(responseJson => {
    try {
    this.setState({
    city: responseJson.data[0].city_name,
    country: responseJson.data[0].country_code,
    temp: responseJson.data[0].temp,
    wind: responseJson.data[0].wind_spd, 
    humidity: responseJson.data[0].rh,
    pressure: responseJson.data[0].pres,
    description: responseJson.data[0].weather.description,
    today: responseJson.data[0].ts,
    timezone: responseJson.data[0].timezone,
    isLoading: false, 
    }, () => {

      localStorage.setItem('weather', JSON.stringify(this.state))
    })
    } catch {
      toast.error('Error Code 429')
    }
  });
}

  getWeather = async (suggestionOrValue, isSuggestion) => {
    if(isSuggestion) {
      const city = suggestionOrValue.name;
      const country = suggestionOrValue.country;
      const unitType = (this.state.unit === 'C') ? 'M' : 'I';

      try {
        // 1. weatherbit current data
        const api_call4 = await fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?` + 
        `city=${city}&country=${country}&units=${unitType}&key=${API_KEY3}`)
        const data4 = await api_call4.json();

        // 2. weatherbit forecast data
        const api_call3 = await fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily` + 
        `?city=${city}&country=${country}&units=${unitType}
&days=6&key=${API_KEY3}`)
        const data3 = await api_call3.json();

        // 3. weatherbit hourly data
        const api_call2 = await fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/hourly` + 
        `?city=${city}&country=${country}&units=${unitType}
&key=${API_KEY3}&hours=10`)
        const data2 = await api_call2.json();

        // 4. iplocation -> sunrise,sunset,moonrise and moonset
        const api_call = await fetch(`${IP_LOCATION}&lat=${data4.data[0].lat}&long=${data4.data[0].lon}`)
        const data = await api_call.json();
        console.log('DATA', data)

        if(city) {
        this.setState({
          temp: data4.data[0].temp,
          city: data4.data[0].city_name,
          country: data4.data[0].country_code,
          humidity: data4.data[0].rh,
          wind: data4.data[0].wind_spd,
          description: data4.data[0].weather.description,
          pressure: data4.data[0].pres,
          error: "",
          precip: data3.data[0].pop,
          forecastdays: data3.data,
          hourlyforecast: data2.data,
          today: data4.data[0].ts,
          timezone: data4.data[0].timezone,        
          maxTemp: data3.data[0].app_max_temp,
          minTemp: data3.data[0].app_min_temp,
          sunrise: data.sunrise,
          sunset: data.sunset,
          moonrise: data.moonrise,
          moonset: data.moonset,
          isLoading: false
        }, () => {
          localStorage.setItem('weather2', JSON.stringify(this.state))
        })
      } else if(city === '') {
        this.setState({
          temp: this.state.temp,
          city: this.state.city,
          country: this.state.country,
          humidity: this.state.humidity,
          wind: this.state.wind,
          description: this.state.description,
          pressure: this.state.pressure,
          forecastdays: this.state.forecastdays,
          hourlyforecast: this.state.hourlyforecast,
          today: this.state.today,
          timezone: this.state.timezone,
          precip: this.state.precip,
          maxTemp: this.state.maxTemp,
          minTemp: this.state.minTemp,
          sunrise: this.state.sunrise,
          sunset: this.state.sunset,
          moonrise: this.state.moonrise,
          moonset: this.state.moonset,
          error: toast.error("City cannot be empty",{
            autoClose: 3000
          })
        })

      } 
      }

      catch {
        toast.error('No Data Received', {
          autoClose: 3000
        })
       }

      localStorage.getItem('weather2')
    }
  }

// toggles between fetchWeather and getWeather
  notifyChange = () => {
    if(this.state.lat && this.state.lon) {
      this.fetchWeather()
    } else {
      this.getWeather()
    }

  }

// Gets the unit value when toggled i.e from celcius to fahrenheit
onUnitChange = (newUnit) => {
    this.setState({
        unit: newUnit
    }, () => {
      this.notifyChange()
    })

    console.log('UNIT NOW', this.state.unit)
}
```

I get `fetchWeather()` toggle unit value perfectly but, not `getWeather()` as it gets back to current user location weather info (i.e `fetchWeather()`) and displays previous toggled unit value which is not desirable. Any appropriate solution or suggestion highly appreciated.

How to tackle this problem and get an efficient solution

Comment: I don't mean to be a pedant (actually maybe I do) but the two method names are a bit confusing

Comment: how do you invoke getWeather method without params? it's required isSuggestion to work correctly

Comment: @JonB I mean to say that when its current location it must call fetchWeather() else if its not then it should call getWeather()

Comment: @zemil What params are required for getWeather()?

Comment: you can see into condition (*isSuggestion*) also you have *suggestionOrValue* arg. But you don't pass these params

Comment: isSuggestion is the boolean defined in another component and suggestionOrValue is based on the above boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass *isSuggestion* arg so the method works incorrect.

Try to delete the condition or pass params.

```
getWeather = async (suggestionOrValue, isSuggestion) => {
    // I guess you should delete this condition and method params
    // because you don't use these params in code example
    // if(isSuggestion) {
```